# Snowflake sql stored procedure bind variable not set

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I try to run in snowflake the following sql stored procedure with a declare variable inside   but i got the following error : Error: Bind variable for object MYTABLE AS MYTABLE not set (line 13).

when I hard code the value into the function identifier it's work by the way...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBNAME.SCHEMANAME."SP_test"()
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
declare 
MYTABLE varchar := 'DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME';
--MYRESULT varchar;
BEGIN

     --  let MYTABLE varchar := 'DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME';
     --  MYTABLE := 'DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME';
    
    --filter to return 1 row
     --  let  MYRESULT  varchar   :=  (  select  col1    from  IDENTIFIER( 'DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME' )   where col2=2 ) ;
     
     --ko
     let  MYRESULT  varchar   :=  (  select  col1    from  IDENTIFIER( :MYTABLE  )   where col2=2 ) ; 

     return :MYRESULT;


end;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_test"()
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
declare
    MYRESULT resultset;
    MYTABLE varchar := 'SERGIU_TESTDB.PUBLIC.CITIBIKE_TRIPS';
    MYVAL varchar;
  
BEGIN

    MYRESULT := (select ride_id from identifier(:MYTABLE) limit 1); 
    let c1 cursor for MYRESULT;
    for row_variable in c1 do
        MYVAL := row_variable.ride_id;
    end for;
    return MYVAL;

END
$$;
```

Calling it:

```
CALL "SP_test"();
```

I get a value out of it:

```
B1CE81D802D68DF8
```

Comment: Hi @sergiu, thanks for your reply, Any way without a cursor ? In the case i pass the value directly into the identifier it's works but by using a variable not... I also  try the solution to do a select MYVAL into :Myval but for an unknown reason it's doesnt work trough Microsoft SSIS

Comment: @vlo I didn't find another way of making it work. At least not without a cursor. Using a variable name or a variable as an argument gives me always a compilation error.